# What is Adobe Server 3?

Tags: services, port

My nmap scan revealed the port with adobeserver3 label (TCP 3703). What is Adobe Server 3, and what does it do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port 3703 is used by the [Adobe Version Cue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Version_Cue) server. This will be the application this is referring to.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that "Adobe Server 3" refers to [Adobe flash media server](http://www.adobe.com/uk/products/flash-media-server-family.html)

However although a port may be registered with IANA for a particular purpose, there is nothing to stop you configuring almost any service to listen on that port (e.g. an Apache HTTPD server). Alternatively there is nothing to stop some malware listening on that port for remote control or command connections.

Use `netstat` to identify the program listening on that port.